# How to make the trigger which controller the insert by checking condition inside JSON object

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to create the trigger which will control the data insertion having age greater than 100 inside the JSON_object.
My trigger creating code

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `avoid_larage_age` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `json_data` 
FOR EACH ROW 
SET @x INT;
x = JSON_EXTRACT(NEW.json_column, '$.age')
IF x &gt; 100 
THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE '02000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Warning: Age is two high'; 
END IF;
```

My expected output.
[image: Expected error while inserting data.]

[image: Error creating trigger]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code to control the data insertion.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `avoid`;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `avoid`
BEFORE INSERT ON `json_data`
FOR EACH ROW
IF JSON_EXTRACT(NEW.json_column, '$.age') > 5 
THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE '02000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Warning: Age is two high'; 
END IF
```